# Magento Virtual Product, Parent Product and Child Product Options

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, virtual-products

I have been browsing here around for a long time and got the most answers from stack overflow and stack exchange.

Now here is a more complicated one:
I have virtual products, which are for different regions.

- Voucher US
- Voucher EU
- Voucher Asia

I want to get them all into one product.
But each one of them has 3 more options:

```
Parent Product (Voucher)
VoucherUS
-Option1
-Option2
-Option3
VoucherEU
-Option1
-Option2
-Option3
VoucherAsia
-Option1
-Option2
-Option3
```

The Costumer would select the Product, then Region, Option1 is based on the region, if Region is US, then Option1 has 5 Options. if Region is EU, then Option1 has 12 Options.
Option2 is same for all regions and Option3 is the Voucher Amount.

I could solve this with 3 different products, each region has its own product. However, I was trying to make the order process more simple. Other websites in the same business, have up to 10 steps until the payment page. We would lower this to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since configurable products with custom options don't work out of the box, a solution without custom code is:

1. make region and option attributes that are set to be used for configurable products
2. create a simple product for each option/region combination
3. create one configurable product with region and option as configurable attributes

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this question, it does not work.
I have created:

- voucher Attribute Set
- the Attributes US/EU/Asia
- configurable Product with the voucher Attribute Set
- 3 Different virtual Products with the voucher Attribute Set
- added those virtual Products to the configurable Product

Until here everything works as intended. I choose the Configurable product and have the EU/US/Asia option.

After I go back and add costume options to those virtual products, the configurable product is out of stock. Tried many things to resolve it, it just does not work.

I will have to solve this with CMS pages. Sadly.